# Reducing memory usage by newspaper3k

Tags: python, memory-management, python-newspaper

I am trying to host a.newspaper spider to send news to my phone every day. However I noticed that deleting an Article object does not free the memory and this takes up around 200MB RAM per run. I am currently running the spider in a separate .py file to avoid RAM full. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you find out something in the meantime?